# ArrayList only conserve the last entry

Tags: java, android, arraylist

i'm trying get the content of an Arraylist but it only has the last value but repeated for the size of the array ( if i add 5 object, it will only show the last object 5times). 
 and i don't know why.

where i insert data

```
try{
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
            Countries coun = new Countries();
            for(int i=0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(i);

                //          Log.i(TAG, "Nom Pays :  " + jsonObject.get("name"))
                coun.setNom((String) jsonObject.get("name"));
                coun.setCode((String) jsonObject.get("code"));

             //   Log.i(TAG, "- - - "+ coun+"- - - " );

                country.add(coun);
            }
        }catch (JSONException je){
            je.printStackTrace();
        };

        Log.i(TAG, "- - - "+ country+"- - - " );

        Iterator it= country.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){
            Log.i(TAG, "- - - "+ it.next()+"- - - " );
        }
```

and when i try to see the data on the Array like that " Log.i(TAG, "- - - "+ country+"- - - " ); "  it show me this 
[image]

and with the iterator it give the same result.  I've put the instaciation of the ArrayList on the class

```
private ArrayList<Countries> country = new ArrayList<Countries>();
```

i don't know why it give me that result

Could someone give me a hint pls

Comment: Move the `Countries` instantiation to inside the loop. As you have it now, you're just updating and adding the one instance each time through the loop.

Comment: move `Countries coun = new Countries();` inside the loop

Comment: Much thanks, now that you say it, it seem obvious xD